# Installed SQL Server 2008 and now TFS is broken

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server

My W2K3 server was running TFS 2008 SP1, SQL Server 2005 Development edition.
I installed SQL Server 2008 Standard.  I installed it while leaving SQL Server 2005 alone.  Upgrading was not possible due to the differences in editions of the SQL Servers.

Now TFS is broken.  On a client computer, if I go Team -> Connect to Team Foundation Server, I  get this error:

> Team Foundation services are not available from server myserver.
>   Technical information (for administrator):
>   TF30059:  Fatal error while initializing web service.

So I head on over to my event viewer on the server.  Under Application, I see one warning and two errors.  First, the warning:

> Source:  SQLSERVERAGENT
>   Event ID:  208
>   Description:
>   SQL Server Scheduled Job 'TfsWorkItemTracking Process Identities Job' (0x21F395C1F444CA499A63EBF05D717749) - Status: Failed - Invoked on: 2010-04-26 13:30:00 - Message: The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 9 (ProcessIdentitiesSchedule).  The last step to run was step 1 (Process Identities).

Then the first error:

> Source:  TFS Services
>   Event ID:  3017
>   Description:
>   TF53010: The following error has occurred in a Team Foundation component or extension:
>   Date (UTC): 4/26/2010 5:36:29 PM
>   Machine: myserver
>   Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/799623628/Root/Services-2-129167769888923968
>   Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727
>   Process Details:
>     Process Name: w3wp
>     Process Id: 4008
>     Thread Id: 224
>     Account name: DOMAIN\TFSService
>
> Detailed Message: TF53013: A crash report is being prepared for Microsoft. The following information is included in that report:
>   System Values
>   OS Version Information=Microsoft Windows NT 5.2.3790 Service Pack 2
>   CLR Version Information=2.0.50727.3053
>   Machine Name=myserver Processor Count=1
>   Working Set=34897920
>   System Directory=C:\WINDOWS\system32
>   Process Values
>   ExitCode=0
>   Interactive=False
>   Has Shutdown Started=False
>   Process Environment Variables
>   Path = C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
>   PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.PSC1
>   PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = x86
>   SystemDrive = C:
>   windir = C:\WINDOWS
>   TMP = C:\WINDOWS\TEMP
>   USERPROFILE = C:\Documents and Settings\Default User
>   ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files
>   FP_NO_HOST_CHECK = NO
>   COMPUTERNAME = myserver
>   APP_POOL_ID = Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool
>   NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 1
>   PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = x86 Family 16 Model 5 Stepping 2, AuthenticAMD
>   ClusterLog = C:\WINDOWS\Cluster\cluster.log
>   SystemRoot = C:\WINDOWS
>   ComSpec = C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
>   CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files
>   PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 16
>   PROCESSOR_REVISION = 0502
>   lib = C:\Program Files\SQLXML 4.0\bin\
>   ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\Documents and Settings\All Users
>   TEMP = C:\WINDOWS\TEMP
>   OS = Windows_NT
>
> Request Details
>   Url=http://myserver.domain.local:8080/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx [method = POST]
>   User Agent=Team Foundation (devenv.exe, 10.0.30128.1)
>   Headers=Content-Length=390&Content-Type=text%2fxml%3b+charset%3dutf-8&Accept-Encoding=gzip%2cgzip%2cgzip&Accept-Language=en-US&Authorization=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%2f6h5U30CEXgoAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACQAyAEgAVABUAFAALwB0AGkAdABhAG4ALgBoAHkAcABlAHIAaQBvAG4ALgBsAG8AYwBhAGwAAAAAAAAAAAA%3d&Expect=100-continue&Host=myserver.domain.local%3a8080&User-Agent=Team+Foundation+(devenv.exe%2c+10.0.30128.1)&X-TFS-Version=1.0.0.0&X-TFS-Session=b7e7fdec-e7ee-48fc-92e8-537d1cd87ea4&SOAPAction=%22http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2fTeamFoundation%2f2005%2f06%2fServices%2fRegistration%2f03%2fGetRegistrationEntries%22
>   Path=/Services/v1.0/Registration.asmx
>   Local Request=False
>   User Host Address=10.0.5.78
>   User=DOMAIN\Johnny [auth = NTLM]
>
> Application Provided Information
>   Team Foundation Application Information
>   Event Log Source = TFS Services
>   Configured Team Foundation Server = http://myserver:8080
>   License Type = WorkgroupLicense
>   Server Culture = en-US
>   Activity Logging Name = Integration
>   Component Name = CS
>   Initialized = No
>   Requests Processed = 0
>
> Exception: TypeInitializationException
>   Message: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.IntegrationResourceComponent' threw an exception.
>   Stack Trace:
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.IntegrationResourceComponent.RegisterExceptions()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Global.Initialize()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.TeamFoundationApplication.Init()
>   Inner Exception Details
>   Exception: ReflectionTypeLoadException
>   Message: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>   Stack Trace:
>      at System.Reflection.Module._GetTypesInternal(StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.SqlResourceComponent.RegisterExceptions(Assembly assembly)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.IntegrationResourceComponent.RegisterExceptions()
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.IntegrationResourceComponent..cctor()
>
> Application Domain Information
>   Assembly Name=mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
>   Assembly Version=2.0.0.0
>   Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
>   Assembly File Version:
>   File:             C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
>   InternalName:     mscorlib.dll
>   OriginalFilename: mscorlib.dll
>   FileVersion:      2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>   FileDescription:  Microsoft Common Language Runtime Class Library
>   Product:          Microsoft® .NET Framework
>   ProductVersion:   2.0.50727.3053
>   Debug:            False
>   Patched:          False
>   PreRelease:       False
>   PrivateBuild:     False
>   SpecialBuild:     False
>   Language:         English (United States)
>
> Assembly Name=System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
>   Assembly Version=2.0.0.0
>   Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll
>   Assembly File Version:
>   File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll
>   InternalName:     System.Web.dll
>   OriginalFilename: System.Web.dll
>   FileVersion:      2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>   FileDescription:  System.Web.dll
>   Product:          Microsoft® .NET Framework
>   ProductVersion:   2.0.50727.3053
>   Debug:            False
>   Patched:          False
>   PreRelease:       False
>   PrivateBuild:     False
>   SpecialBuild:     False
>   Language:         English (United States)
>
> Assembly Name=System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
>   Assembly Version=2.0.0.0
>   Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll
>   Assembly File Version:
>   File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll
>   InternalName:     System.dll
>   OriginalFilename: System.dll
>   FileVersion:      2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>   FileDescription:  .NET Framework
>   Product:          Microsoft® .NET Framework
>   ProductVersion:   2.0.50727.3053
>   Debug:            False
>   Patched:          False
>   PreRelease:       False
>   PrivateBuild:     False
>   SpecialBuild:     False
>   Language:         English (United States)
>
> Assembly Name=System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
>   Assembly Version=2.0.0.0
>   Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll
>   Assembly File Version:
>   File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll
>   InternalName:     System.Xml.dll
>   OriginalFilename: System.Xml.dll
>   FileVersion:      2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>   FileDescription:  .NET Framework
>   Product:          Microsoft® .NET Framework
>   ProductVersion:   2.0.50727.3053
>   Debug:            False
>   Patched:          False
>   PreRelease:       False
>   PrivateBuild:     False
>   SpecialBuild:     False
>   Language:         English (United States)
>
> Assembly Name=System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
>   Assembly Version=2.0.0.0
>   Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll
>   Assembly File Version:
>   File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll
>   InternalName:     System.Configuration.dll
>   OriginalFilename: System.Configuration.dll
>   FileVersion:      2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>   FileDescription:  System.Configuration.dll
>   Product:          Microsoft® .NET Framework
>   ProductVersion:   2.0.50727.3053
>   Debug:            False
>   Patched:          False
>   PreRelease:       False
>   PrivateBuild:     False
>   SpecialBuild:     False
>   Language:         English (United States)
>
> Assembly Name=Microsoft.JScript, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
>   Assembly Version=8.0.0.0
>   Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll
>   Assembly File Version:
>   File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll
>   InternalName:     Microsoft.JScript.dll
>   OriginalFilename: Microsoft.JScript.dll
>   FileVersion:      8.0.50727.3053
>   FileDescription:  Microsoft.JScript.dll
>   Product:          Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) 2005
>   ProductVersion:   8.0.50727.3053
>   Debug:            False
>   Patched:          False
>   PreRelease:       False
>   PrivateBuild:     False
>   SpecialBuild:     False
>   Language:         Language Neutral
>
> Assembly Name=App_global.asax.4nq_g1xi, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>   Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
>   Assembly Version=0.0.0.0
>   Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\services\87e24ff8\921625fe\App_global.asax.4nq_g1xi.dll
>   Assembly File Version:
>   File:             C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\services\87e24ff8\921625fe\App_global.asax.4nq_g1xi.dll
>   InternalName:     App_global.asax.4nq_g1xi.dll
>   OriginalFilename: App_global.asax.4nq_g1xi.dll
>   FileVersion:      0.0.0.0
>   FileDescription:
>   Product:
>   ProductVersion:   0.0.0.0
>   Debug:            False
>   Patched:          False
>   PreRelease:       False
>   PrivateBuild:     False
>   SpecialBuild:     False
>   Language:         Language Neutral
>
> Assembly Name=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
>   Assembly Version=9.0.0.0
>   Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\services\87e24ff8\921625fe\assembly\dl3\9051eeb6\603ea9a2_d822c801\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.DLL
>   Assembly File Version:
>   File:             C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\services\87e24ff8\921625fe\assembly\dl3\9051eeb6\603ea9a2_d822c801\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.DLL
>   InternalName:     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.dll
>   OriginalFilename: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.dll
>   FileVersion:      9.0.21022.8
>   FileDescription:  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.dll
>   Product:          Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) 2008
>   ProductVersion:   9.0.21022.8
>   Debug:            False
>   Patched:          False
>   PreRelease:       False
>   PrivateBuild:     False
>   SpecialBuild:     False
>   Language:         Language Neutral
>
> Assembly Name=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
>   Assembly Version=9.0.0.0
>   Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
>   Assembly File Version:
>   File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
>   InternalName:     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
>   OriginalFilename: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
>   FileVersion:      9.0.30729.1
>   FileDescription:  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll
>   Product:          Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) 2008
>   ProductVersion:   9.0.30729.1
>   Debug:            False
>   Patched:          False
>   PreRelease:       False
>   PrivateBuild:     False
>   SpecialBuild:     False
>   Language:         Language Neutral
>
> Assembly Name=Microsoft.TeamFoundation, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
>   Assembly Version=9.0.0.0
>   Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.TeamFoundation\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll
>   Assembly File Version:
>   File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.TeamFoundation\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll
>   InternalName:     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll
>   OriginalFilename: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll
>   FileVersion:      9.0.30729.1
>   FileDescription:  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.dll
>   Product:          Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) 2008
>   ProductVersion:   9.0.30729.1
>   Debug:            False
>   Patched:          False
>   PreRelease:       False
>   PrivateBuild:     False
>   SpecialBuild:     False
>   Language:         Language Neutral
>
> Assembly Name=System.Security, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
>   Assembly Version=2.0.0.0
>   Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll
>   Assembly File Version:
>   File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll
>   InternalName:     System.Security.dll
>   OriginalFilename: System.Security.dll
>   FileVersion:      2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>   FileDescription:  System.Security.dll
>   Product:          Microsoft® .NET Framework
>   ProductVersion:   2.0.50727.3053
>   Debug:            False
>   Patched:          False
>   PreRelease:       False
>   PrivateBuild:     False
>   SpecialBuild:     False
>   Language:         English (United States)
>
> Assembly Name=System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
>   Assembly Version=2.0.0.0
>   Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
>   Assembly File Version:
>   File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
>   InternalName:     system.data.dll
>   OriginalFilename: system.data.dll
>   FileVersion:      2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
>   FileDescription:  .NET Framework
>   Product:          Microsoft® .NET Framework
>   ProductVersion:   2.0.50727.3053
>   Debug:            False
>   Patched:          False
>   PreRelease:       False
>   PrivateBuild:     False
>   SpecialBuild:     False
>   Language:         English (United States)
>
> Assembly Name=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Library, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
>   Assembly Version=9.0.0.0
>   Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Library\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Library.dll
>   Assembly File Version:
>   File:             C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Library\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Library.dll
>   InternalName:     Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Library.dll
>   OriginalFilename: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Library.dll
>   FileVersion:      9.0.30729.1
>   FileDescription:  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.Library.dll
>   Product:          Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) 2008
>   ProductVersion:   9.0.30729.1
>   Debug:            False
>   Patched:          False
>   PreRelease:       False
>   PrivateBuild:     False
>   SpecialBuild:     False
>   Language:         Language Neutral
>
> Assembly Name=System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
>   Assembly CLR Version=v2.0.50727
>   Assembly Version=2.0.0.0
>   Assembly Location=C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll
>   As

And finally, the second error:

> Source: Team Foundation Error Reporting
>   Event ID: 5000
>   Description:
>   EventType teamfoundationue, P1 1.0.0.0, P2 tfs, P3 9.0.30729.1, P4 9.0.0.0, P5 general, P6 typeinitializationexcept, P7 4758b22a940fe6d9, P8 d15c14bb, P9 NIL, P10 NIL.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be using SQL Server Standard Edition (a license for TFS-only use of SQL Standard is included with TFS). Developer Edition is not licensed for use with TFS.

Answer (score 1):

We just did this in house but this was not the recommended approach that we found when we researched the method.  In order to move from SQL 2005 to SQL 2008 you need to do an in-place upgrade because you cannot change the hostname of the SharePoint database server AND you need some of the sysmessages entries from the master database.  If you can I would recommend starting over and following this outline, assuming you have a database and application tier in your TFS environment.

Roll back your changes:
 - Install a new SQL 2005 Standard edition instance on a new server OR uninstall and re-install the old instance using the proper edition
 - Move the databases to the new instance using backup/restore or attach
 - Add the application accounts back to the instance as logins
 - If you used a new server the create a DNS CNAME record that points the old server name to the new server name
 - Verify that your TFS installation works again

Upgrade to SQL 2008:
 - Perform an in-place upgrade of SQL 2005 to SQL 2008
 - You may need to update the SQL 2008 OLAP and Native Client providers on the application tier of your TFS install

Also, check out this link to see if it has anything in it that can help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that both the services for SQL Server 2005 and 2008 are not running at the same time.  My guess is that they are both using either (a) the same port, or (b) the same named pipe.  You may be able to stop the services associated with one version of the server without having to uninstall the other.  More than likely they are conflicting with eachother, since TFS has to make a connection (even when locally) using network resources.

Answer (score 0):

I am having exactly the same problem.

I managed to partially fix the problem by installing SP1 for team file system, and then stoping all sql server 2008 windows services (like icemage suggestion).

By Partially fix, i mean that basic functionality is restored (checkin/checkout by clients) but anything more advanced that uses reporting services is still broken. (web interfaces + creation of new team progects).